# is there a way to check if user is currently "signed in with apple" in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I have a flutter app with 2 authentication methods:

1. Based on device id (associated with account during account creation)
2. Sign in with apple
   I need to know whether user is currently signed in with apple on each app launch.

Why I need that:
When device id is not found in my back end, I send user to registration page, where user has 2 options to register:

1. regular registration
2. sign in with apple

The problem is that device id can be changed on ios upgrade, app reinstall etc. Therefore if user signed in with apple first time, but then his device id has changed, I want to remove sign in with apple button. Because for that particular case user is supposed to go through regular sign in method where he needs to enter phone number he entered during the registration and if he confirms SMS code, then account is linked to new device id and access is restored. I don't want them to click sign in with apple again, because during regular sign ins I only get tokens from apple and can't get apple id email anymore.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thank you